# Blender crashes when opening the particle editor

Tags: particles, hair

The title explains it all really. I tried to create a sphere with a hair particle, when I switch to the particle edit mode blender crashes. I'm working on an iMac 2017. I've seen other people have reported this problem online but havnt seen a solution to the problem.

The rest of blender works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this myself, so I thought I would post it in case anyone else has the same problem.

Blender seems to crash when entering particle edit while still in the render view mode. Switching back to shading view seems to solve it.